# Where is the -ConfigurationTypeName located?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to run a add-migration via my .net MVC project.  There are two DBContext in a DBContext folder.  However, when I run the command:

```
add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName xxxxx.Configuration -Name SavedSearches
```

it tells me:

> The migrations configuration type 'xxxxx.Configuration' was not be found in the assembly 'xxxxx'.

Where do I find the proper name/namespace for the configuration type (i.e. what folder is it in, what level)?  I've tried to search, but nothing clearly states it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the Tools menu, click Library Package Manager and then Package Manager Console.
At the PM> prompt enter the following commands:

- **enable-migrations**
- **add-migration InitialCreate**
- **update-database**